# Infopath forms not added to central admin after deploying workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, central-administration, form

I am making changes to several SharePoint state machine workflows that each contain Infopath forms for the workflow tasks. I have been able to deploy all but one of them successfully. The problem I am having is that the forms in the workflow are not pushed to the Manage Form Templates section of Central Admin. For all the other workflow projects, installing the workflow using a .bat file worked fine, and updated the form templates.

The first time I tried to deploy this workflow, the forms did not change at all in CA. I saw errors when attempting to upload new versions manually

> "The following form template cannot be upgraded because it is not currently uploaded on this farm"

I uninstalled the feature that contained the forms, which deleted them, but on all subsequent deploys of completely new versions/GUIDs for everything, the forms don't get add to the template list in CA. If I try to upload the templates manually in CA, the forms have a value of No for Workflow Enabled, which prevents me from opening them in SharePoint.

I have researched for many hours with no solution. I have read and completed step-by-step the following articles:

- http://shopsharepoint.blogspot.com/2006/07/this-form-cannot-be-opened-it-is-not.html
- https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2283766?wa=wsignin1.0
- http://www.sharepointassist.com/2009/06/22/this-form-cannot-be-opened-it-is-not-workflow-enabled/

The structure of my project folder in 14/TEMPLATES/FEATURES is:

- Forms folder (includes all .xsns, elements.xml and workflow.xml)
- Workflow1 folder (includes elements.xml)
- Feature.xml

If anyone could give advice that would be great.

Comment: Anyone? Should I change the tags? ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem but I found the solution. In my SharePoint workflow project in Visual Studio, the .xsn in my Forms folder was not a "published" Infopath form. I didn't have access to the SharePoint server (my Infopath install was on a different VM) so I was just saving the Infopath template and sending it to the other VM.

This can cause your template to not be added to Central Admin. So **the fix for me was to publish the form to a network location**. Make sure you clear the alternate access path in the wizard. After deploying the .WSP, my form was added to Central Admin "Manage Form Templates" with a value of **Yes** for Workflow Enabled.

Also verify the following:

- The security level of your form is Domain or Full Trust.
- You have the "GloballyAvailable" and "RegisterForms" settings correctly set in the feature manifest (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2283766?wa=wsignin1.0))
- Your Form URN is correct in the Workflow1/Elements.xml file (and workflow.xml file if applicable).

[This blogpost](http://blog.larslynch.com/2010/01/problems-with-infopath-forms-and.html) is also a good checklist for this problem.